# Как связать php скрипт с сайтом

Tags: php, веб-программирование, сервер, веб-сервер, клиент-сервер

Доброго дня, уважаемые форумчане, такой вопрос.
У меня есть php программка , которая работает локально на моём ПК(поменял пару параметров и  запустил при помощи php.exe в командной строке). Как сделать так(или где почитать об этом), чтобы я мог через сайт указывать эти самые параметры и эти параметры передавались бы в этот скрипт и он начинал бы работать. Как это все устроено? Хотя бы в каком направление читать.... читал про веб-сервисы, полная каша в голове

Comment: Крайне невнятно поставлен вопрос. Какие параметры и куда передаются. Что есть "сайт"?

Comment: Вам нужен настроенный HTTP-сервер. Выбирайте любой (nginx, apache, lighttpd ...). Если вы новичек в этом, можно начать с готовой сборки (XAMPP, WAMP, LAMP, Denwer...)

Comment: @SlyDeath  Добрый день! Вас интересует тип или название параметров ? или что-то другое... Сайт, как сайт даже не знаю, что ещё добавить. Вводишь параметры нажимаешь кнопку начать, эти параметры ( как разъяснили ниже) по POST запросу передаются в этот скрипт и начинает выполнение.

Comment: @tutankhamun Добрый день, да у меня стоит WAMP)

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите и читайте про `GET` и `POST` запросы, чем отличаются и тд, смотрите про массив `$_REQUEST`.

То есть ваша программка будет лежать скажем: `http://domain.com/my.php` и вы будете к ней обращаться к примеру: `http://domain.com/my.php?param1=hello&param2=world&param3=123`

В скрипте получите массив `$_REQUEST`, где будет подобное:

```
$_REQUEST["param1"] = "hello";
$_REQUEST["param2"] = "world";
$_REQUEST["param3"] = "123";
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! а несколько скриптов могут одновременно работать?

Comment: @IvanG. сколько будет запросов, столько может быть и скриптов

Comment: @tutankhamun спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите GET и POST запросы.
Для взаимодействия вашего сайта со скриптом можно использовать формы,
пример формы регистрации

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
<input name="name">
<input name="password>
<button type="submit">Зарегистрироваться</button>
</form>
```

`method="POST"` означает, что вы используете POST запрос, отличие POST запроса от GET в том, что данные формы будут скрыты.
`action="index.php"` указывает путь на файл с вашим исполняемым php скриптом, по нажатию на кнопку данные будут отправлены в файл index.php.
В файле index.php для получения данных используйте глобальный массив $_POST,
например: `$_POST['name']` будет содержать значение, введенное вами в поле с именем "name".

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ!